# PHP preg_match group repetition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a (php5.2 and 5.3) regex that needs to extract the first $x sentences from a user post (which may include email addresses and hyperlinks) and am having trouble trying to find out why (and yes, it's an ugly regex; I'll optimise it when it works):

```
/^(([^.!?]+|(\w+[.@?&=%:])+\w+)+[.!?]+\s){0,4}/
```

returns the first four sentences, but

```
/^(([^.!?]+|(\w+[.@?&=%:])+\w+)+[.!?]+\s){0,5}/
```

returns no matches.  It's my understanding that {0,5} should match the previous group between 0 and 5 times, and as such should still work if it can only match it 4 times.

Can anyone shed some light on this behaviour?

Update: $x is just an arbitrary number; using {0,$x} in the regex.  Post is filtered to be sentences separated by a single space. Sorry for the ugly expression... been looking into this for a couple of days now, and it's doing my head in... Made the changes suggested by sawa.  My main question is about the behaviour, and the content that the group matches shouldn't matter that much.

Update2: This is essentially what I'm doing:

```
function extractSummary($message, $limit) {
  $expr = '/^(([^.!?]+|(\w+[.@?&=%:])+\w+)+[.!?]+\s){0,'.$limit.'}/';
  $msg = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xff]/', "\n" strip_tags($message));
  $msg = trim(preg_replace('/(\n|\s|&nbsp;)+/', ' ', $msg)).' ';
  preg_match($expr, $msg, $summary);
  return $summary[0];
}
```

A sentence (in my mind at least, without going into NLP territory, cos its just for one function in the site) is anything up to a period, exclamation point or question mark, but periods can appear within the sentence in an email address of URL.  The last version of this regex just counted up to 5 periods, and thus broke on links and email addresses.

Update 3: Reallising that I've just added even more horrible code, I'll explain the last.  Some posted content was found to have non-printing chars (like \r, etc) that didn't play nicely with the regex, so I remove non-printing chars with the first preg_replace.  The second replaces any further whitespace groups with a single space, so the sentences are hopefully separated by exactly one space.

Comment: What are $x sentences? How is the post like?

Comment: Before doing that, you should clean up your regex. For example, you do not need the outermost pair of parentheses in `((\w+[....\w)`, and you are not consistent about captures: sometimes you have `(...)`, while sometimes you have `(?:...)`. Use the former only when you want to extract that part. I think it is not polite to just post a complicated regex and let people follow it.

Comment: Thanks for following the suggestion, but I think some example sentences are necessary, or at least you should tell us what you have in mind as a sentence. Is a sentence simply a sequence up to a period? Speculating from what you have, this is probably not the case. Is a period allowed within a sentence only when it's a part of an email address? What is the condition that defines a sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognize sentence as follows:

A sentence is:

- a shortest sequence up to a period, exclamation, or a question mark,
- optionally followed by a single or double quotation,
- obligatorily followed by a space or the end of string.

This requirement of a space or the end of string takes care of periods in email addresses because periods in email addresses do not appear right before a space or at the end of a string.

```
/[^ ](?:.*?[.!?]['"]*(?= |\z)){0,4}/
```

Comment: This results in no matches, even in a basic case. Trying with "This is a sentence. This is sentence 2. This sentence has an email.address@domain.com. This has a link http://somewhere.com. This sentence should not appear in output."

Comment: Yes, tried both.  Update on before, result is not no match, but match is an empty string.  Which makes sense from the regex, but is not what I'm after - I need to extract the sentences, not test a match.

Comment: That extracts the first sentence only.  With a minor alteration, it gets the first 4 sentences: "/(.*?[.!?](?=\s)){0,4}/", however still breaks when it encounters an email address or link.

Comment: Does not handle sentences which end with quotes, e.g. `Like "this one".` or `He said: 'it didn't work!'`

Comment: I was wrong about where to add the quotation marks. I fixed it, and edited the whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

The regex ends by unconditionally matching a whitespace character. If there are exactly 5 sentences in the input and no whitespace after the last period, the first will match but the second won't.

Comment: That does not explain why it succeeded in the first regex while failing in the second one, as Rodney states.

Comment: The post has a space inserted at the end, before it is run through the regex, to avoid this eventuality.

Answer (score 0):

This tested function should do the trick:

```php
function get_sentences($text, $x) {
    $regex = "/\A(?:.*?[\w\"'][.?!](?=['\"]?\s|\$)){0,{$x}}/ms";
    if (preg_match($regex, $text, $matches)) return $matches[0];
    return ''; // Never get here (will always match).
}
```

Here is a commented version of the regex:

```php
$regex = '/# Match first $x sentences, each ending in [.?!]
    \A                # Anchor to beginning of string
    (?:               # Non-capture group to apply count
      .*?             # Lazily match zero or more characters.
      [\w"\']         # Last char before end is word or quote.
      [.?!]           # End of sentence puntuation [.?!]
      (?=[\'"]?\s|$)  # But only if followed by space or EOL
    ){0,5}            # Match from zero to $x sentences.
    /smx';
```

Note that this also handles sentences that end with quotes, e.g. `"This one."` or `"This one!"` or 'This one"?

Comment: Nice, but stops output before a sentence with a link in it: eg "This is sentence one. This is two. This is someone@somewhere.com three." only outputs "This is sentence one. This is two." even if $x > 2.

Comment: @Rodney: No. It works just fine with your example, The ending punctuation is required to be followed by whitespace or end of line.

Comment: My bad, mistyped your expression.  Works well.  Thanks heaps!